# Set QtCreator default run configuration (not Terminal)

Tags: qt, qt-creator

When I start a new project in QtCreator it defaults to run in Terminal. I know I can change this, not to run in Terminal -- following the instructions from http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-run-settings.html.

But how do I change that so it persists to new projects?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the [shared project settings](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-sharing-project-settings.html) system can be leveraged to get the setting to stick.